# Using the Python API to read from Google Cloud Storage with minimal permissions

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-iam, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-python

I would like to download blobs from a storage using Python. The examples show this code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKETNAME)
blob = bucket.get_blob(BLOBNAME)
raw_bytes = blob.download_as_bytes()
```

While this works, it not only requires the `storage.objects.get` permission granted with the "Storage Object Viewer" role (`roles/storage.objectViewer`), but also the `storage.buckets.get` Permission to execute the get_bucket line. This permission is granted by other roles that sound either overly powerful or legacy, like "Storage Admin" or "Storage Legacy Bucket Reader".

Is there a way to change the Python code, such that only the `storage.objects.get` permission is required? It seems that the JSON API which is probably behind the Python API allows this: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get

Best, Boris

Comment: 1) You can create custom IAM roles. 2) Legacy in the name **Storage Legacy Bucket Reader** does not mean legacy as in no longer recommended or supported. It refers to permissions that existed before IAM was developed. Before IAM, OAuth Scopes were the authorization mechanism.

Comment: But the question remains: how can I read the blob without the storage.buckets.get permission using Python? If I can do that using the JSON API, it would be sad if the implementation of the Python API prevents that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample code, the bucket statement **bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKETNAME)** is used to **list the bucket operation**.

If you are to output the value you get as a response, rather than performing the client.get_bucket, you can pass this as a **static value**.
By using a static value, you would not be utilizing the client.get_bucket operation which requires the storage.buckets.get permission.

You may also refer to a similar [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745795/how-to-download-a-file-from-google-cloud-platform-storage).